# SQL Server 2005 Full text search - Valid Thesaurus characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

`FORMSOF THESAURUS` throws errors for specific character. E.g. `FORMSOF (THESAURUS, hel!lo)` throws an error whereas `FORMSOF (THESAURUS, hel?lo)` works.

However, I did not find any documentation about which characters are allowed.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thesaurus is expecting a word or term:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300(v=sql.110).aspx

What I do in my .NET code is use a regex to remove all those special characters (basically leaving A-Z and 0-9.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258227(v=sql.80).aspx

says:

> word
>
> Is a string of characters without
>   spaces or punctuation.
>
> phrase
>
> Is one or more words with spaces
>   between each word.

**Make sure you have your stop words setup (I did have changed to have none of them in my code)**

Stopwords

> When defining a full-text query, the
>   Full-Text Engine discards stopwords
>   (also called noise words) from the
>   search criteria. Stopwords are words
>   such as "a," "and," "is," or "the,"
>   that can occur frequently but that
>   typically do not help when searching
>   for particular text. Stopwords are
>   listed in a stoplist. Each full-text
>   index is associated with a specific
>   stoplist, which determines what
>   stopwords are omitted from the query
>   or the index at indexing time. For
>   more information, see Stopwords and
>   Stoplists.

There is also an awesome library for .net here: (I used that to transform phrases in full text queries)
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+(2008)/64248/

EDIT:
This might help:
Note that I did replace 's to nothing or else That's becomes Thats and would be a no match.

```
search = search.Replace("’s", "");
search = Regex.Replace(search, @"[#$%&()*“”+,./:;<=>!?@[\\\]^_`’{|}~]", "");
```